# How to create a image button in sencha touch?

Tags: android, button, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I want to create image buttons in Sencha touch 2 application. For that i define a cls properties for button and added in app.css file. But the background is not showing for the buttons..

Here is my index.html class

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Auto Generated with Sencha Architect -->
<!-- Modifications to this file will be overwritten. -->
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Teritree</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" id="phonegap" src="cordova-1.8.1.js"></script>
    <script src="sencha-touch-all.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app/app.js"></script>
     <script>
        Ext.Loader.setConfig({ disableCaching: false });
        Ext.Ajax.setDisableCaching(false);    
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        if (!Ext.browser.is.WebKit) {
            alert("The current browser is unsupported.\n\nSupported browsers:\n" +
                "Google Chrome\n" +
                "Apple Safari\n" +
                "Mobile Safari (iOS)\n" +
                "Android Browser\n" +
                "BlackBerry Browser"
            );
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Here is my button code:

```
xtype: 'button',
                            docked: 'left',
                            cls: 'wishlogbtn',
                            height: 200,
                            margin: 50,
                            width: 150
```

And i added ths line in the app.css file:

```
  .wishlogbtn
{
    background-image: url('../wishlog.png');
}
```

I dont know whether i am doing coreect or not as i am new to this platform. Please help..

Comment: have you added `!important` to that property yet?

Comment: But when i am clicking the button i want to give focus to it or change the background..how can i make it??

Comment: just a simple javascript problem, you can google it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am able to resolve it. The problem is with path of the image.

Comment: I believe the resolution was that a the `url()` specified in a css file  must be relative to the css file, not to the html pages using the css.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but you can try this:

```
.wishlogbtn
{
    background-image: url('../wishlog.png') !important;
}
```

or

```
.wishlogbtn
    {
-webkit-mask-image: url('../wishlog.png');
background: white;/*or smthing*/
}
```

If all other fails, you can just use html property

```
xtype:'button',
html:'<img src="..."/>'
```

There is also a lot of available icons in <sencha_dir>\resources\themes\images\default\pictos\ that you can include in your .scss (SASS) file with

```
@include pictos-iconmask('user');/*replace "user" with any name of .png file in that folder"*/
```

and then you can use it like that in sencha:

```
xtype: 'button',
iconMask: true,
iconCls: 'user' /* use the same name as in .scss*/
```